# No Logo at PayPal Pro Direct Payment option at checkout

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-pro

I just set up PayPal Pro direct payment in my magento. Now the "checkout" has two options:

PayPal and Direct Payment (VISA MC etc) options. For the PayPal option it has a PayPal logo.

For the direct payment it has no logos.

I've tried to change the frontend experience settings, but nothing helps.My goal is to insert **VISA Master Card logos** right next to the VISA MC option.

Also have tried to customize checkout page at manager.paypal.com but that doesn't hep either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method in the link below worked well for me. Just inserted the code they recommend into the second line of the cc.phtml, made sure that the image of a proper size exists in the specified location and the logo is there...
https://github.com/sudheerpal/MagentoPaymentMethodLogo